# Conditional normality in linear regression models

Tags: regression, normality-assumption, joint-distribution, conditional-expectation

In linear regression models, a convenient assumption is that the vector of error terms *u<sub>1</sub>*,...,*u<sub>n</sub>* = u is (multivariately) normally distributed conditional on X, the (stochastic) matrix of all regressors. In combination with the assumptions that 1) *E[u<sub>i</sub>|X] = 0 (i = 1,...,n)*, 2) *Var[u<sub>i</sub> | X] = σ<sup>2</sup> (i = 1,...,n)* and 3) *Cov(u<sub>i</sub>,u<sub>j</sub> | X) = 0 (for all i ≠ j)*, it must then hold that
u | X ~ N(**0**,σ<sup>2</sup>**I**<sub>n</sub>).
Now, can we say that u<sub>1</sub>,...,u<sub>n</sub> are (stochastically) independent of X, such that the conditional distribution of u | X is equal to the unconditional distribution of u, u | X = u ~ N(**0**,σ<sup>2</sup>**I**<sub>n</sub>) ?

If I take the joint density of (u,X), f(u<sub>1</sub>,...,u<sub>n</sub>,x<sub>11</sub>,...,x<sub>nk</sub>) = $f(u,X)$, and consider the conditional density f(u<sub>1</sub>,...,u<sub>n</sub> | x<sub>11</sub>,...,x<sub>nk</sub>) = $f(u | X)$, it holds in general that $f(u|X)$ = $\frac{f(u,X)}{f(X)}$.
Now if u and X are independent of each other, $f(u,X) = f(u)f(X)$, such that $f(u|X)$ = $f(u)$. But I don't understand why this should be the case?

From assumption 1) *E[u<sub>i</sub>|X] = 0 (i = 1,...,n)* it only follows that cov(u<sub>i</sub>,x<sub>kj</sub>) = 0 for all i,j,k, which is not the same as independence. And there is no restriction on the joint distribution of (u,X).

---

Comment: Assumptions 1) 2), 3) do not imply in any way normality of the error, conditional or unconditional. This is a separate assumption.

Comment: I know that conditional normality is an additional assumption. And I'm interested in its implications, in particular the relation of u and X.